# How to change font size in the app on button click using React native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

In my react native application I need to add + and - buttons in settings screen to increase or decrease the font size in the entire app when we click on those buttons from settings screen.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a broad question, at high level You need to manage font-size value globally via  Context API or Redux, then use that value when you define  TextInput font size.

Answer (score 0):

one way to make this is to create a state and update the `fontsize` on style

example:

```
const [fontSize, setFontSize] = useState(14);

    return (
      <p style={{fontSize: `${fontSize}px`}}>
         My text
      </p>
      <button onChange={() => setFontSize(fontSize + 1)}>More</button>
      <button onChange={() => setFontSize(fontSize - 1)}>Less</button>
    );
```

to make this you can set this `fontSize` at top level.

another way to make this is add any CSS lib and set the same state in a global CSS using the `*` on css

Comment: You can't use CSS in React Native.